# python not able to push data to mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

Below code takes html registration form data and suppose to pushes that to mongoDB.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template, flash,redirect,url_for,session,logging
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField,PasswordField,validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
import bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_NAME'] = 'amitesh_DB'
app.config['MONGO_HOST'] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'you are logged in as' + session['username'] # gives the message and the name of the username that is logged in that session.
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    #users = mongo.db.users
    #   users.find_one({'name' : request.form['username']})
    return ''

#we are checking if the username that we are registering doesn't exist, if it does, it will return index.html

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST','GET'])
def register():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        users = mongo.db.users #connecting the collection called "users" in mongoDB
        existing_user = users.find_one({'name':request.form['username']})# we are looking for a name in the mongoDB in the collection "users" that is a username that we are registering with.

        if existing_user is None:#if the above request.form doesn't find the username with a name that we enter in the html form, then this "if" will allow the new username to register.
            hashpass = bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['pass'].encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
            users.insert({'name': request.form['username'],'password' : hashpass})
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

        return 'username already exist' # means, "existing_users" wasn't none
    return render_template('register1.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'mysecret'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have below questions::

1) Even though I have mentioned the DB name, server address, and collection, but I do not see the data in mongo, my mongo is working, and my python code can communicate to it, as a proof, below are some messages from mongo screen::

```
 [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49849 #1 (1 connection now open)
 [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49849 conn1: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows 7", architecture: "AMD64", version: "6.1.7601-SP1" }, platform: "CPython 2.7.12.final.0" }
 [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49850 #2 (2 connections now open)
 [conn2] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49850 conn2: { driver: { name: "PyMongo", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows 7", architecture: "AMD64", version: "6.1.7601-SP1" }, platform: "CPython 2.7.12.final.0" }
 [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49851 #3 (3 connections now open)
 [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:49851 conn3: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.4.4" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 7", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.1 SP1
```

2) In the python code, I have used bcrypt to encrypt my password while inserting text in the password filed, but its still plain text. Not sure if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got some work around. I tried to integrate a mLab(web application) with this python code, and now I can see that the new collection with the name "users", and the username/password is stored there in Json format. But why the code is not able to connect to my mongo installed localhost.